# How to activate Recoverit when 'csrutil' doesn't *on macbk pro 10.13.6

Tags: macbook-pro, command-line

Terminal messaged 'failed to modify system integrity configuration. This tool needs to be executed from the Recovery OS.' Where is Recovery OS.Objective to recover data from Emptied Trash...precious family videos in mp.4.

Answer (score 1):

To disable SIP, you need to run `csrutil` from the Recovery OS, which you can boot into by holding cmd-r while turning Mac on until the Apple logo shows (Terminal can be accessed in the Utilities menu).

Comment: You may also disable SIP from another OS instance or from EFI (using rEFInd for example).  See : http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/sip.html